# Failed TestNG tests with DataProvider in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng, parameterized-unit-test

i recently started playing around with tdd and ran into a problem where i do not understand why one thing is working and the other one doesnt.

the following code works for me:

```
public class Ant {

    public Ant(Point startLocation, Point hive) {
        this.currentLocation = new Point(startLocation);
        this.hive = new Point(hive);
    }

    public void goHome() {
        if (hive.x > currentLocation.x) {
            currentLocation.x++;
        } else if (hive.x < currentLocation.x){
            currentLocation.x--;
        }
        if (hive.y > currentLocation.y) {
            currentLocation.y++;
        } else if (hive.y < currentLocation.y){
            currentLocation.y--;
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding test:

```
@DataProvider(name = "goneHome")
public static Object[][] goHome() {
    return new Object[][] {
            {new Point(2,1), new Point(3,2), new Point(7,8)},
            {new Point(20,1), new Point(19,2), new Point(7,8)},
            {new Point(23,10), new Point(22,9), new Point(7,8)},
            {new Point(2,10), new Point(3,9), new Point(7,8)},
            {new Point(2,8), new Point(3,8), new Point(7,8)},
            {new Point(7,1), new Point(7,2), new Point(7,8)}
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "goneHome")
public void testGoHome(Point currentPosition, Point nextPosition, Point hive) 
    throws Exception {
    Ant ant = new Ant(currentPosition, hive);

    ant.move();
    assertEquals(ant.getCurrentLocation(), nextPosition);
}
```

the test fails if i change the ant constructor like this:

```
public Ant(Point startLocation, Point hive) {
    this.currentLocation = startLocation;
    this.hive = hive;
}
```

By failing i mean that the test with the first two sets of the DataProvider work correctly, the rest is failing/not finishing.
Although i am not quite sure what failed. If i remove the first two sets of data in the DataProvider, still only the first two datasets (which where the 3rd and 4th data set before) do not fail.

I use **IntelliJ** and the symbol besides the "failed" test is still the "loading icon".

Debugging each single test case shows that the points are set correctly. Removing the assert from the test does not change anything.

Can someone explain this behavior to me please?

Thanks in advance

Egon

Edit: corrected the version of the constructor that failed

Comment: Did you try to run tests as Maven goal? Maybe it's a bug in Idea

Comment: it worked with maven, thanks! i spent way too long thinking about this^^

Comment: Even the smartest tool can fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a bug in IntelliJ IDEA. Sometimes I also facing with this problem. Unfortunatelly it's still (2014-11-24) unresolved: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100752

Try run your tests with alternate runner (as Maven goal, for instance).

Comment: it worked with maven, thanks! i spent way too long thinking about this, sorry i cant give you a up as i am new to stackoverflow